# Can not handle JDBCConnectionException in spring rest with custom exception handler

Tags: spring, rest, exception

I use a global exception handler in my spring rest app and I would like to hide jdbc exceptions, but it doesn't work as expected. I shut down the database to force a connection exception and I can see the following exception in the log and I receive the default spring error response, but not the one I defined in the exception handler

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve parameter [1] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> ...
throws java.io.IOException: No suitable resolver
```

Here's the code.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomGlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler({JDBCConnectionException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> dbError(JDBCConnectionException exception,
            HttpHeaders headers,
            HttpStatus status,
            WebRequest request) throws IOException
    {
        Map<String,Object> body = new HashMap<>();

        body.put("errorId",Long.valueOf(201));
        body.put("state",HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.value());
        body.put("message", "internal failure");
        body.put("time", new Date().toString());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(body, headers, status);
    }
```

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the failure...spring can not resolve these two parameters, for that kind of exception.

```
HttpHeaders headers,
HttpStatus status
```

It's obviouse the exception mentioned paramter [1]

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve parameter [1] in public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> ...
throws java.io.IOException: No suitable resolver
```

I removed these two parameters and the exception handler handles the exception.

This code works now

```
@ExceptionHandler(JDBCConnectionException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> dbError(Exception ex,
            WebRequest request) 
    {
        Map<String,Object> body = new HashMap<>();

        body.put("errorId",Long.valueOf(201));
        body.put("state",HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.value());
        body.put("message", "internal failure");
        body.put("time", new Date().toString());
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(body, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the annotation implies `@ControllerAdvice` is used as an extension on your REST endpoints, these exception handlers will process the exception for the **REST API** and does not influence how it is logged in the console. It will instead determine how exceptions are reported to your end users and allow you to write concise error messages without leaking information about your program.

If you want to completely catch an exception and not only for the REST API take a look at [this blog](https://www.baeldung.com/java-global-exception-handler).

However I would not recommend doing this since this will greatly reduce the information available to you as a developer, this information cannot be seen by end users and therefore the REST API custom exception should provide enough abstraction.

I hope this helps you.